# factor not factorizing x axis labels for plotly

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, rstudio, plotly

I have a dataframe imported from excel.
one of the column is of the format :

```
dates
-------
Oct-17
Nov-17
Dec-17
Jan-18
Feb-18
Mar-18
Apr-18
May-18
Jun-18
Jul-18
Aug-18
```

All other columns are just numbers

When I plot it using plotly (line chart), I am getting my x axis in alphabetical order. I tried factor.But it is not working.

```
 data_ = read_excel(path="Sample.xlsx",sheet = 'sheet1')
  data = as.data.frame(data_)
 data$dates <- factor(data$dates, levels = data$dates)
```

What has to be done? Finally I need x axis labelled with months in this format `Oct-18,Nov-18`

plot code :

```
pred <- plot_ly(data_, x = ~dates, y = ~exp, name = 'Exp', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~acc, name = 'Accumulated', line = list(color = 'rgb(22, 96, 167)', width = 4)) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~sts, name = 'Contract', line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4, dash = 'dash')) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~stat, name = 'Status ', line = list(color = 'rgb(22, 96, 167)', width = 4, dash = 'dash')) %>%
    layout(title = "Trend",
           xaxis = list(title = "Months"),
           yaxis = list (title = "")"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass the argument `ordered = TRUE` inside the `factor()` function, the order of your levels will be the order they appear when you print `data$dates`. This is also the order they will appear in the plot. The default behaviour if you don't set `ordered = TRUE` is to arrange character factors by alphabetical order.

**EDIT**

To programatically get the `dates` column in the right order, you may try the following code (it depends on `dplyr` and `stringr` packages):

```
levels <- data %>%
  distinct(dates) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    year = stringr::str_split(dates, "-", simplify = TRUE)[2],
    month = stringr::str_split(dates, "-", simplify = TRUE)[1], 
    month = match(month, month.abb)
    ) %>% 
  arrange(year, month) %>% 
  pull(dates)
```

Now you just pass this `levels` vector to the `levels` argument inside `factor()`

Comment: `data$dates <- factor(data$dates, levels = data$dates, ordered =TRUE)` This is not making any change. I am still getting it sorted in alphabetical order

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what's happening without a reproducible example, but the problem may be that you're passing the whole `dates` column to `levels`. It should work if you pass a vector with the levels in the order you want (eg: `levels = c("Oct-17", "Nov-17", ...**other dates in order**, "Aug-18")`).

Comment: but this is dynamic.. new month will be added each month

Comment: `[1] "Dec-17" "Jan-18" "Feb-18" "Mar-18" "Apr-18" "May-18" "Jun-18" "Jul-18"
 [9] "Aug-18" NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA      
[17] NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA      
[25] NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA      
[33] NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA      `

Comment: Sorry It was because of a typo from my end

Comment: In that case you have to get your levels programatically. I will edit the answer with a code snippet that may solve your problem.